# How to add space between bitmap of spinner selector and items of drop down list

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have following spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/safe_network_time_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"
    android:entries="@array/schedule_edit_days_repeat"
    android:popupBackground="@drawable/custom_dropdown_white_background"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider4"
    tool:listitem="@layout/custom_dropdown_spinner_button" />
```

The spinner_selector is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
       <bitmap android:gravity="right|center_vertical"  android:src="@drawable/down_red_arrow" />
    </item>
 </selector>
```

The dropdown list appears like this:

[image: dropdown list]

When I select an item of the dropdown list, if it is too long it overlaps the arrov bitmap. how can I avoid this?

[image: selected item]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `layer-list`

`bg_spinner.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <!-- This is the actual spinner background -->
        <selector >
            <!-- Feel free to use your own drawable for these states -->
            <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_border_accent_thin"/>
            <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_border_accent_thin"/>
            <item android:state_window_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_border_grey_thin"/>
        </selector>
    </item>

    <!-- This is the spinner drawable, use your custom drawable aswell. android:right does the magin to separate this drawable from  the spinner content-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_ripple_arrow"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:right="16dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

---

### Edit 02/02/2020

My apologies for a weekend-long lunch.

If you are using the `androidx` dependencies (which I suggest you do) here's the code that I use to properly add spacing between the text and the selected item in the spinner.

**On your layout.xml**

```xml
<!-- The line I think you need is the one giving padding to the right -->
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="36dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner"
    android:popupBackground="@drawable/bg_spinner_popup"/>
```

The `bg_spinner.xml` is the one provided a couple of lines above.

And the popup one doesn't really matter, since it gives some directives on how to paint a background, nothing important but here it is either way...

`bg_spinner_popup.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
       android:shape="rectangle">
     <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
     <solid android:color ="@android:color/white"/>
     <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="@color/primaryColor"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: The given code has to be in your `resources/drawable` folder. Right click there and `add new drawable resource`

Comment: Yes, I added your code in a new drawable and used that as the background of the spinner but it seems something is wrong, the arrow is stretched as in the new picture I posted

Comment: Let me give you an answer after lunch :)

Comment: Sorry once again. Do u know how if it is possible to align the selected item of the spinner to the right, next to the arrow icon?

Comment: Try making the item view match_parent and set the text view label to gravity right